# How to save and load refresh token in Google Python APIs

Tags: python, access-token

I'm very happy with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548319/641264 because thanks to it, now I understand well difference between access token and refresh token. I also throwed a glance at the OAuth2WebSercer documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer
But I don't know the functions/methods that can be used to work with refresh token. For access token, we use:

```py
gdata.gauth.ae_save()
gdata.gauth.ae_load()
token.get_access_token()
```

But what about refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

If you step your way down into the source:
[[ae_save source]](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/gauth.py?r=3b021605570f6ab46ecd306e0c0d15e74b8cfa15#1576)
[[token_to_blob source]](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/gauth.py?r=3b021605570f6ab46ecd306e0c0d15e74b8cfa15#1431)

you'll see that `token_to_blob` is called on the token itself when you call `ae_save`.

In particular:

```
elif isinstance(token, OAuth2Token):
  return _join_token_parts(
      '2o', token.client_id, token.client_secret, token.scope,
      token.user_agent, token.auth_uri, token.token_uri,
      token.access_token, token.refresh_token)
```

so not just the access token is saved, but many other attributes of the token object.

Comment: How can I use refresh token? Using refresh token.refresh_token gives an error.

Comment: This should not be the case. What is the `type(token)`? Even if you don't have a refresh token, the value will be `None`. Before you serialize the token via `ae_save`, make sure you actually have the `refresh_token`. Subsequent OAuth2 requests won't give you a new refresh token unless you specify `approval_prompt=force`.