# Google Calendar API access with Python

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm currently devlopping a simple native Python application to interact with my Google Calendar. In order to do it, I'm using the Google Calendar API for the first time thanks to the Google Python library.

However and despite of the documentation, I'm deadlocked with the insertion of a new event in my calendar. Here is a part of my code for connecting and executing my request :

```
import sys
...
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run

...

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    redirect_uri='http://localhost')

storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, storage)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

try:
  event = {
    "start": "2013-02-20T09:00:00.000+01:00",
    "end": "2013-02-20T11:00:00.000+01:00",
    "summary": "New event",
    "location": "Paris, FRANCE"
  }
  service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
  print "END"
except AccessTokenRefreshError:
  print ('Credentials have been revoked')
```

Once executed, that's what I got :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I've tried a lot of things so far, including all the code samples that I found over the reference documentation of the Google Calendar API but nothing has changed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you signed up for an API account at https://code.google.com/apis/console?

Comment: Yes, of course. I forgot to say that I've tried some samples codes from the Google documentation with success.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with virtually the same code. Try adding this line to your client_secrets.json file:
"access_type":"offline"

This will ensure that you get a refresh token back and not a token that expires after an hour.

Details here: [Google Calendar API v3 - How to obtain a refresh token (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546907/google-calendar-api-v3-how-to-obtain-a-refresh-token-python)

Comment: You should also remove any existing credentials.dat file and force the user to re-authorize access using the new client_secrets.json parameters for this to work.

Comment: As of today (9/24/14) I am unable to get the refresh token to work using flow_from_clientsecrets, but it works fine with OAuth2WebServerFlow, just FYI