# Google Cloud - oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-prediction

I got this error message when trying to execute Google Prediction API.

```
raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

My credential details

```
{
    "scopes": [],
    "private_key": "XXXXX",
    "id_token": null,
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "token_info_uri": null,
    "token_response": null,
    "client_id": null,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
    "token_expiry": null,
    "_class": "SignedJwtAssertionCredentials",
    "refresh_token": null,
    "_module": "oauth2client.client",
    "private_key_password": "notasecret",
    "access_token": null,
    "service_account_name": "account-1@myapp-1136.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "invalid": false,
    "assertion_type": null,
    "kwargs": {},
    "client_secret": null,
    "revoke_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke",
    "user_agent": null
}
```

Comment: Is this a transient error? This usually just means your access token has expired, and needs to be refreshed with oauth2client.client.Credentials.refresh().

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Oldish question but this helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/14288818/785808

Answer (score 3):

For future readers of this question, if this issue happens locally it can be caused by an out of sync system clock. Otherwise, this was also a known issue on App Engine at around the same time this question was posted. Details of both causes can be found in an issue report on the oauth2client GitHub project page from last year:

[**oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Bad Request**](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/451)